# Is it possible to configure my celery periodic tasks outside of the Django settigns file? I can't import my tasks into settings

Tags: python, django, django-celery-beat

Here's how my project is organized.

```
electron /
  ...
  electron / <----- sources root (pycharm)
    ...
    electron /
      ...
      celery.py
      settings.py
    tasks /
      tasks.py <----- Here are my tasks
```

celery beat configuration in settings.py

```
from celery.schedules import crontab 
from tasks import tasks
   
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        "toutes-les-minutes": {
            "task": "tasks.tache_journaliere",
            "schedule": crontab(minute="*/1"),
        },
    }
```

When I import my tasks like this: from ..tasks import tasks.
I get the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

When I import tasks like this: from tasks import tasks,the following error occurs

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I've been trying to correct these errors for a while, but it doesn't work. I even looked for solutions here. I still can't.

Is it not possible to configure periodic tasks outside of the settings.py file? (in the celery.py file for example)

Comment: You're getting the second error because you're importing a file with models; or one that does so. If you move the import statement into the function itself; the error will likely go away. Most people use https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to schedule their celery tasks efficiently; and without downtime. There's some good courses for free on youtube to get you started with the basics, and advanced concepts of celery.

Comment: @nigel239 I just forgot to do the same thing for my serializers in my tasks. Everything works fine now. Thank you.